# How to debug into TCL source?

Tags: gdb, tcl

I need to step into TCL source from my code in gdb. I built TCL with debug symbol enabled, but still cannot step into it. Here are what I did:

Build TCL

```
./configure --prefix=<path to my tcl build> --enable-symbols=all
make
make install
```

Build my code

```
gcc -g -O0 -I <path to my tcl build>/include -L<path to my tcl build>/lib -ltcl8.6 m.c

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to my tcl build>/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Run gdb

```
gdb ./a.out
<inside gdb>dir <path to tcl source>/generic
```

But when I try to step into TCL call like Tcl_Init() and Tcl_ParseCommand(), gdb simply steps over.

When I run "info sharedlib" in gdb, I get this:

```
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x0000003cf6400b00  0x0000003cf64198eb  Yes (*)     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7c91350  0x00007ffff7db0518  Yes         <path to my tcl build>/lib/libtcl8.6.so
0x0000003cf681ea60  0x0000003cf694024c  Yes (*)     /lib64/libc.so.6
0x0000003cf7000de0  0x0000003cf7001998  Yes (*)     /lib64/libdl.so.2
0x0000003cf7802120  0x0000003cf780d3a8  Yes (*)     /lib64/libz.so.1
0x0000003cf7405760  0x0000003cf74110c8  Yes (*)     /lib64/libpthread.so.0
0x0000003cf6c03e70  0x0000003cf6c43fb8  Yes (*)     /lib64/libm.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

Do you see what might be the problem?

I am using TCL8.6.1.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tcl.h>

int main()
{
    const char *my_tcl = "set a 100;";
    size_t my_tcl_len = strlen(my_tcl);

    Tcl_Interp *interp = NULL;

    if ((interp = Tcl_CreateInterp()) == NULL) {
        perror("Tcl_CreateInterp");
        return -1;
    }

    if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
        perror("Tcl_Init");
        return -1;
    }

    Tcl_Parse parse;

    if (Tcl_ParseCommand(interp, my_tcl, my_tcl_len, 0i, &parse) != TCL_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", Tcl_GetStringResult(interp));
        return -1;
    }

    printf("All right.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would check what --enable-symbols=all does, and check the command lines to see if -g is provided.  You can easily check if the debuginfo is there using something like "readelf -wi .../libtcl.so".

Comment: Even just plain `--enable-symbols` on its own should make things easy to debug into. Check that you're linking against the right build of things. And add `Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);` before the `Tcl_CreateInterp` call; it initialises the Tcl library itself.